# Pattern works differently in `systemctl list-units`

Tags: linux, systemctl

I wrote 4 service file in `/etc/systemd/system` directory, which are `sybase.service`, `sybase-backup.service`, `sybase-rs.service`, `sybase-rsm.service`, they all works fine.

When I try to list them out using `systemctl list-units sybase*`, it reports:

*0 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.*

If I use `systemctl list-units sybase\*` or `systemctl list-units "sybase*"`, I got the correct result.

But for some other services, like `systemctl list-units ssh*` or `systemctl list-units "ssh*"`, both works.

So why the difference?

Comment: I think you have files named `sybase...` in your working directory where you are running the command. So try to ru the command from another location by `cd`-ing to it first. For example `cd /`  then run the command.

Comment: yes, I checked the directory, exactly like what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must **quote or escape** any special characters such as wildcards (*), caret (^) or dollar signs ($) when passing them as arguments to the command, or they will be expanded by the shell. See the **EXPANSION** section of the bash.1 and glob.7 man page for a complete list of special characters.

#### How does bash handle `*`

From `glob.7` manpage

> Empty lists
> The  nice  and  simple rule given above: "expand a wildcard pattern into the list of matching pathnames" was
> the original UNIX definition.  It allowed one to have patterns that expand into an empty list, as in

> ```
>       xv -wait 0 *.gif *.jpg
> ```
>
> where perhaps no *.gif files are present (and this is not an error).  However, **POSIX requires that  a  wild‐
> card  pattern  is  left  unchanged  when it is syntactically incorrect, or the list of matching pathnames is
> empty**.  With bash one can force the classical behavior using this command:

In the particular case of how `*` behaves in the bash, if a pattern like `ssh*` can have many files in the current directory, such as `ssh_config sshd_config`, it would be expanded as such, or it would be passed to the command as is.
This behaviour should not be relied upon. It is better to quote or escape special characters each time.

#### Analysis of the commands

> systemctl list-units "ssh*"
> systemctl list-units sybase* or systemctl list-units "sybase*" will give the correct result.

These commands work because all the "*" is quoted or escaped, so it is passed to `systemctl`.

> systemctl list-units ssh*

This command will work if your current working directory does not contain any files beginning with ssh. However, it will fail if the current working directory does contain these files.

> systemctl list-units sybase*

The working directory where this command is executed contains files that start with `sybase.` Therefore, `sybase*` has been expanded to a list of these files and then passed to the `systemctl` command.